# How do I find out if a exclamation mark is at the end of a string?

Tags: python

I am writing a program that replaces exclamation marks that are at there **end** of the string with Bork Bork Bork!!

I have tried using the `replace()` function but that replaces exclamation marks in the middle of a string.
eg.

```
output = ("Hello! coder").replace("!", ". Bork Bork Bork!")
```

Would output

```
print(output)
```

Hello. Bork Bork Bork!! coder

When it should only replace "!" with "Bork Bork Bork" **When it is at the END of a string.**

Thank you.

Comment: `re.sub(r"!$", ". Bork Bork Bork!", s)` is that what you want?

Comment: ggorlen Could you please explain what this code does? re.sub(r"!$", ". Bork Bork Bork!", s)

Comment: Replaces using a regular expression anchored to the end of the string. Any regex tutorial will explain `$`.